# Is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}=\pi$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, sequences-and-series, special-functions

It seems that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}=\pi.$$
But I can't prove it. I cannot prove that the function is decreasing in $x$ either.

Comment: Use the Poisson summation formula for both.

Comment: Isn't this also the Riemann sum for $\int_{\infty}^\infty dx/ (1 + x^2)$?

Comment: Indeed. Bad question... Thank you both.

Comment: Should I just delete it?

Comment: More generally: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^2+x^2} = \pi\coth(\pi x).$$

Comment: A related post on [math.se]: [Formula for the series $f(x):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{x^2+n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978921)

Comment: Well, this question was a clear miss. But perhaps the computationally inclined will be interested in this speedup trick I used: For $\displaystyle P(k)=ak^n+bk^{n-1}+ck^{n-2}+dk^{n-3}+\cdots$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{P(k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{P(k)}+\frac{1}{(n-1)a(N-\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}}-\frac{b}{na^2(N-\frac{1}{2})^{n}}-\frac{n}{24a(N-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}+\frac{b^2-ac}{(n+1)a^3(N-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}+\frac{b(n+1)}{24a^2(N-\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}}+\frac{-b^3+2abc-a^2d}{(n+2)a^4(N-\frac{1}{2_{\,}\!})^{n+2}}+\frac{\mathcal{O}(1)}{N^{n+3}}$